# Single/Double quote in prettier

Tags: prettier, prettier-eslint

I'm having a funny behaviour with prettier and eslint. I want to use single quotes in strings in ts/js context and double quotes in jsx context.

If I use single quote (in .tsx file) I get this error:

```
  243:21  error  Replace `'Children\'s·Foundation·Trust'` with `"Children's·Foundation·Trust",`  prettier/prettier
```

If I use double quote in the same line:

```
  243:21  error  Strings must use singlequote
```

This is my .prettier.js config

```json
    {
      "printWidth": 120,
      "trailingComma": "es5",
      "singleQuote": true,
      "jsxSingleQuote": false,
      "arrowParens": "avoid"
    }
```

this is my eslint

```json
    module.exports = {
      "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "plugin:prettier/recommended",
      "plugin:import/typescript"
    ],
      "rules": {
      "arrow-body-style": 0,
        "react/prop-types": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": 0,
        "quotes": [2, "single"],
        "jsx-quotes": [2, "prefer-double"]  
      ],
        "camelcase": 0,
        "arrow-parens": ["error", "as-needed"]
    
      },
      "settings": {
      "polyfills": [
        "Promise",
        "fetch",
        "Object",
        "Array.from",
        "URLSearchParams",
        "AbortController",
        "Headers"
      ],
        "react": {
        "version": "detect"
      }
    }
    }
```

I can't work out which rule is conflicting with another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the quotes rules in your `.eslintrc` to:

```json
quotes: ["error", "single", { "avoidEscape": true }]
```

Comment: just a quick side question: what is in few words the point of having both prettier and eslint? to me it seems the first is a subset of the features that the latter offers (code check only)

Comment: Normally, prettier is better at code formatting, while eslint is mainly geared towards finding ambguous/error-prone/bad style statements. There is some degree of overlap. When you have both of them, you always end up having to handle conflicts like that one. There is also an eslint plugin for prettier that somewhat automates this process. Unless it is a big project and you can afford to spend time polishing those, you are better off with only eslint.